# How to pass some string or data from API to an angular component in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I am getting a string from a URI response in the controller of the API. Now i want to take this response(string) to some part inside the angular.

```
string email = jsonResponse.Substring(41, brace - 42);
```

It is the string i want to take to the angular part. the address for the angular is localhost:4200  and localhost:5000 is for the API.

Comment: what you exactly want to achieve? You want to bind the value to template?

Comment: i want to take this string from the api to the angular component

Comment: are you getting the string inside your angular app services?

Comment: I'm getting this string in may .Net API controller.. its in the API part not in the angular part.

Comment: [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX)

Comment: I think you need to take a step back and read up on [how web applications work](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+web+applications+work) especially how they interact with a server for data retrieval. I say this because this question does not make sense and based on the comments and answer I am not the only one that thinks this.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a service in this service you have to add this :

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export class RequestService {
    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}
    apiUrl : string = "http://localhost:5000";
    getResponse() : Observable<string>{
        return this.http.get<string>(this.apiUrl+"/calledMethod");
    }
}
```

in your **app.component.ts** :

```
import { RequestService } from './request.service'
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
        stringResult : string = ""

    constructor(private request : RequestService) {}

   ngOnInit()
   {
        this.showResponse()
   }

    showResponse(){
        this.request.getResponse().subscribe(
            r => this.stringResult = r,
            err => console.log(err)
        )
    }
}
```

To finish in your **app.component.html** :

```
{{stringResult}}
```

Example :
[API request](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nmpzct)

Comment: That's fine! but how do i trigger this getResponce() from the API method since i am inside the API??

Comment: @HurAbbas you are in the API ? I don't understand.

Comment: @HurAbbas you want to create a methode in your api to after that call it in angular ?

Comment: i am getting this string in response to a URI called whose redirect url is localhost:5000, hence after the response is fetched, i am inside the api, now i want to take this result to the angular part.

Comment: Then follow the step the service call your method from your api to get the response, the component put the string in a variable and your html show you the content of the variable.

Comment: When to call it? I want to call it when i get the response string inside the api, not earlier than that.

Comment: @HurAbbas Please follow the step I create a stablitz to show you